# locking pdf viewer in TexStudio

Tags: pdf, texstudio

I find the `pdf` view in TexStudio not really confortable. Especially, when I needs to scroll the `pdf`, I have to fit size to width to make the scroll handy. But, when the viewer is indeed fit to size, then the text is so small, than I can hardly read it. Is there a way to lock the size width, after having ruled the correct scale of the `pdf` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theoretically this can be set in the preferences

[image]

but apparently there is a bug https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/bugs/1380/

---

**Workaround:**

Not not sure when it was introduced, but with version `2.11.2` one can use arrow keys to navigate the pdf viewer. So adjust the zoom to your needs and use the up and down keys to scroll. This will preserve horizontal alignment.